# Move pods between namespace

Tags: kubernetes

Not a big deal, but just wondering what is best practice for moving pods from one namespace to another?

Do you just `kubectl delete` and `kubectl apply`?

Comment: For moving the resources we will need delete and recreate strategy.  But if it's about reaching the app from other app in different namespace it could be good to allow service in one Namespace to talk to a service in another Namespace and we can avoid moving the created pod.

Comment: Please correct me, but I am pretty sure we can do that already via a Service Account and "myapp.othernamespace.svc.cluster.local".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot "move" a resource to another namespace. There might be resource with same name in the other namespace already.

So yes, you need to delete the existing pod and recreate it in the other namespace.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to move a pvc (storage) ? 
We need to rearrange our namespaces and move stuff around, the pds are not a real problem, but the issue is the storage